# interrupt the thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

as you can see this program implements Thread. my question is that how  can i interrupt the thread and show the catch block message?

as i know the main thread should finish after child  thread but what i consider here is my main thread finish before child thread second question is how  can you explain  it?

```
public class cycleone implements Runnable  {
       int  cases;
    Thread thrd;
    cycleone(int pooya){
        cases=pooya;
    }
    //child thread
     public void run(){
         try{
             for(int i=0;i<=14;i++){
                 System.out.println("this is "+i+""+cases);
                 Thread.sleep(600);
                 }
             }
         catch(InterruptedException ext){
             System.out.print("no");
         }
     }

}
```

```
public class cycletwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    cycleone one=new cycleone(4);
    Thread newThrd=new Thread(one);
    newThrd.start();
    // main thread
    try{
        for(int i=0;i<=20;i++){
        System.out.println("/");
        Thread.sleep(200);
        }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException exc) {
        System.out.println("thread is end");
    }
    System.out.println("thread is ending");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You can interrupt the Thread by calling: `newThrd.interrupt()` in your main method right after the try/catch block

2) The main thread finishes before the child thread because 20 times per 200ms `Thread.sleep()` means it's life time is >=20*200 ms

and the child thread's life time is >=14*600 ms

Comment: so can i say it's possible that main thread finish earlier than child thread?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can send an interrupt to the cycleone class is to call the Thread.interrupt method on the newThrd instance you create in cycletwo.